# What variety of tomato grows no taller than about 10 cm?

Tags: tomatoes, variety-selection

I saw a very small tomato plant (I think less than 10cm) in a tiny pot, and it was producing tomatoes. What varieties of tomato grow like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as you mean something like this:

- [Micro Tom Tomato](http://www.tradewindsfruit.com/vegetables/micro_tom_tomato.htm)

You really have two options:

1. Buy a plant (or plants).

   - Maybe you can buy "starts", I honestly don't know.
2. Buy some seeds and grow you own eg

   - [Micro-Tom #6536 (30 seeds) $3.50](http://www.tomatogrowers.com/small.htm) -- no affiliation, just a random site found via a web search.

Either way, there should be "growing", "plant requirement", etc information that comes with your purchase, regardless which option you decide to go with...

---

*Good luck! and please post back a photo or two if you do grow a miniature tomato plant...*